# The Aviation.SE icon should be a different colour.

Tags: feature-request

The current light blue colour makes it look like the site is still in Beta. It should be changed to a distinct colour to indicate that a fully fledged stack exchange site.

Answer (score 8):

> The current light blue colour makes it look like the site is still in Beta.

But we ARE still (partially) in Beta. We are simply undergoing the "two step" graduation, and we are at the first step.

We will be

> a fully fledged stack exchange site.

only after the design will be done, including the icon. And this is part of the second step of graduation, that will include higher reputation requirements.

For more info, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263905)